# How to get delete and added string in between two strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

[image: Sample Output image]

In my requirement i have two strings (Dynamically) i want to compare two strings and strike off the deleted/modified string and also highlight the newly added string. one string is my old string and one string is new string, some times both are same based on user input. i tried but i cant get output. please help me. below is my tried code in c#

```
Ex: string s1 = "Hello dear Alice and dear Bob.";string s2 = " Hello Alice and dear Bob Have a nice day.";
```

Need Output: Hello dear Alice and dear Bob Have a nice day. 
Dear is strike off and Have a nice day is highlight. pLEASE help me friends
My code:

```
if(String.Equals(my_NString,my_String,StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
    sb.AppendLine("<div><p style='text-align:justify;'>"+my_NString+" </p></div>");
    sb.AppendLine("<br/>");
    }
    else
    {
    sb.AppendLine("<p style='text-align:justify;border:3px;border-color:#FF0000;padding:1em;color:red;'>"+my_NString+" </p>");
    sb.AppendLine("<br/>");
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you show your output ?

Comment: Please Refresh browser and click on sample Output image,just now i uploaded image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not so easy. There's no one way to compare strings like that. There are different strategies and each have their up and downs. This is a very complicated task. Your best shot is to use an existing implementation of difference and variation algorithm, like this:
https://github.com/kpdecker/jsdiff (sorry, it's js)

PS: Editted:

Example really depends on what library/engine you'd like to use. The one that I'm most familiar with (and used most often) would look like this:

```
class Difference {
  public static void Main(string[] args) {
    diff_match_patch match = new diff_match_patch();
    List<Diff> diff = match.diff_main("Hello World.", "Goodbye World.");

    for (int i = 0; i < diff.Count; i++) Console.WriteLine(diff[i]);
  }
}
```

The result would be:

```
[(-1, "Hell"), (1, "G"), (0, "o"), (1, "odbye"), (0, " World.")]
```

You could also use `match.diff_cleanupSemantic(diff)`; before displaying, and then the result would be:

```
[(-1, "Hello"), (1, "Goodbye"), (0, " World.")]
```

So basically use `diff_cleanupSemantic` to change level of differences from 'letter-level' to 'word-level'.

Comment: any other possibilites

Comment: i got the deleted words in to list , i need if both deleted,added string or idle string below is my code

Comment: List<string> diff;
                            IEnumerable<string> set1 = my_NString.Split(' ').Distinct();
                            IEnumerable<string> set2 = my_String.Split(' ').Distinct();
                            if (set2.Count() > set1.Count())
                            {
                                diff = set2.Except(set1).ToList();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                diff = set1.Except(set2).ToList();
                            }

Comment: @chaitanay Your soltion is not so good, because if you had 100 words, and only 1 first would differ, then 99 of them would be crossed out and then placed again. So not so good. I pasted a link to `jsdiff`, use it :)

Comment: Ok thanks. but jsdiff is for javascript side i need c#

Comment: You added javascript tag first, sorry. You could use Diff.Net http://menees.com/index.html or this utility: https://github.com/skanmera/NetDiff If you found this answer satisfactory consider upvoting and accepting it.

Comment: This isn't really an answer. It's more of a comment.

Comment: @Enigmativity with an example it would be a valid answer. Doing this manually is not the right way. Danon, add an example (including code) for a dotnet library. Else it's just a link only answer.

Comment: @Mafii - Yes, I agree. With an example showing how it is done then this would be fine.

Comment: I hope @Mafii agrees too

Comment: @Danon Thanks its useful for me. Thank You